# Kotlin math vs Math

Tags: kotlin

I have read [What is the Kotlin exponent operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270435/what-is-the-kotlin-exponent-operator) and try to follow it's answer by writing `val t1 = 23.0` then `print (t1!!.pow(4.9))` in Android Studio REPL Kotlin mode and get for second **error: unresolved reference: pow**. The code which is in other places found by search for Kotlin power function works fine `print (Math.pow(t1,4.0))`. I was puzzled but found that post [Unresolved reference: pow in Eclipse using Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149551/unresolved-reference-pow-in-eclipse-using-kotlin) and when I did `import kotlin.math.pow` next `print (t1.pow(4.9))` started to give a number. Also I noted `import kotlin.Math.pow` gives **error: unresolved reference: Math**, so
1. Why **M**ath.pow but import kotlin.**m**ath?
2. Could I use extension function `pow` w/out importing in REPL something like `t1.math.pow(2.3)` (as it is gives **error: unresolved reference: math**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `Math.pow(10.0, 2.0)`

```
println(Math.pow(10.0, 2.0)) // "100.0"
```

`Math` refers to the [`java.lang.Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class.

You can verify this by calling

```
println(Math::class) // "java.lang.Math"
```

In this case, nothing needs to be imported as the `java.lang` package is imported by default.

---

When using `10.0.pow(2)`

```
println(10.0.pow(2)) // "100.0"
```

`pow` refers to [`fun Double.pow(x: Double): Double`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/pow.html), the Kotlin extension function that needs to be explicitly imported from `kotlin.math.pow`:

```
import kotlin.math.pow
```